# True pixel quantity

Tags: c#, math

I know that my question will be a littel strange but i need realy some help. I have an algorithme to calculate true pixel quantity in a binary image. Her is an example how it work:

Binary Image :

```
0 0 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1  
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Her is the result :

```
18 15 11 8 6 5
16 13 9  7 5 4
11 9  6  5 4 3
5  4  2  2 2 2
2  2  1  1 1 1
```

And this is how it work :

```
Result (i,j) = result (i+1, j) + result (i, j+1) - result(i + 1, j + 1) + Image(i,j)
```

Her an example for the 18  value:

```
18 = 16 + 15 - 13 + 0
```

My question :
What is the name of this algorithm because I need to get some more information about it?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Could you perhaps be meaning convolution filters?

Comment: For others: it's the count of 1-pixels below and to the right of the given pixel, including the pixel itself.

Comment: Non it not a convolution filter and not also a Minesweeper. It can give how many true pixel (or white) in a binary image. If you look to the example we have 18 at the top of the result. If you calculate the number of true pixel in the binary image you will find 18 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called an integral image, or [summed area table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table). It is used to speedup box filtering, among others. It is a 2D generalization of a [prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum).

Comment: Thank very match for your answer